# Cakephp 3 Base table or view not found, table is not plural

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Hi so I made a table called health_records, baked the model and it produced an entity called HealthRecord.php and the table HealthRecordsTables.php. Tried to save data to it and it threw me this error

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'sparkplug.health_record' doesn't exist
```

Below is the code I have for their corresponding files

Controller

```
 public function test() {
    $this->loadModel('HealthRecord');

    $HealthRecord =$this->HealthRecord->newEntity();

    $data = [
        'user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id'),
        'type' => 'test',
        'entry' => ['test' => '1'],
        'meta' => json_encode(['test' => '1']),
    ];

    $HealthRecord = $this->HealthRecord->patchEntity($HealthRecord,$data);
    dd($HealthRecord);
    //$this->HealthRecord->save($healthRecord);

}
```

HealthRecord.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Model\Entity;

use Cake\ORM\Entity;

/**
 * HealthRecord Entity
 *
 * @property int $id
 * @property int $user_id
 * @property string $type
 * @property array $entry
 * @property array $meta
 * @property \Cake\I18n\FrozenTime $created
 * @property \Cake\I18n\FrozenTime $modified
 *
 * @property \App\Model\Entity\User $user
 */
class HealthRecord extends Entity
{

/**
 * Fields that can be mass assigned using newEntity() or patchEntity().
 *
 * Note that when '*' is set to true, this allows all unspecified fields to
 * be mass assigned. For security purposes, it is advised to set '*' to false
 * (or remove it), and explicitly make individual fields accessible as needed.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $_accessible = [
    'user_id' => true,
    'type' => true,
    'entry' => true,
    'meta' => true,
    'created' => true,
    'modified' => true,
    'user' => true
];
}
```

HealthRecordsTables

```
<?php
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Query;
use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;
use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;

/**
 * HealthRecords Model
 *
 * @property \App\Model\Table\UsersTable|\Cake\ORM\Association\BelongsTo $Users
 *
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\HealthRecord get($primaryKey, $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\HealthRecord newEntity($data = null, array $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\HealthRecord[] newEntities(array $data, array $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\HealthRecord|bool save(\Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface $entity, $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\HealthRecord|bool saveOrFail(\Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface $entity, $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\HealthRecord patchEntity(\Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface $entity, array $data, array $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\HealthRecord[] patchEntities($entities, array $data, array $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\HealthRecord findOrCreate($search, callable $callback = null, $options = [])
 *
 * @mixin \Cake\ORM\Behavior\TimestampBehavior
 */
class HealthRecordsTable extends Table
{

    /**
     * Initialize method
     *
     * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
     * @return void
     */
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('health_records');
        $this->setDisplayField('id');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

        $this->belongsTo('Users', [
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Default validation rules.
     *
     * @param \Cake\Validation\Validator $validator Validator instance.
     * @return \Cake\Validation\Validator
     */
    public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
    {
        $validator
            ->integer('id')
            ->allowEmptyString('id', 'create');

        $validator
            ->scalar('type')
            ->maxLength('type', 255)
            ->requirePresence('type', 'create')
            ->allowEmptyString('type', false);

        $validator
            ->requirePresence('entry', 'create')
            ->allowEmptyString('entry', false);

        $validator
            ->requirePresence('meta', 'create')
            ->allowEmptyString('meta', false);

        return $validator;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a rules checker object that will be used for validating
     * application integrity.
     *
     * @param \Cake\ORM\RulesChecker $rules The rules object to be modified.
     * @return \Cake\ORM\RulesChecker
     */
    public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
    {
        $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['user_id'], 'Users'));

        return $rules;
    }
}
```

I tired to clear the model cache and even going into the tmp file and clearing the cache there. 
Also tried deleting the model files and rebaking but nothing seems to work so far. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Solved, I have to also pluralize calling the model so for this case

instead of

```
$this->loadModel('HealthRecord');
```

Has to be

```
$this->loadModel('HealthRecords');
```

and instead of

```
$HealthRecord =$this->HealthRecord->newEntity();
```

has to be

```
$HealthRecord =$this->HealthRecords->newEntity();
```